# How do I send navigation keys and extract data from IBM i Access Client Solutions?

Tags: excel, vba, ibm-midrange, jdedwards

At work I must extract data from an AS400 screen using IBM i Access Client Solutions.

I used to have code that I could use with PComm; however, they recently replaced the software in my company (without asking) and that is causing delays of up to several days.

Here is the old code I had:

```
Option Explicit

Sub JDE()
' Uses Microsoft forms 2.0 object libraries as references
' You must have Pcomm from IBM installed for this to work:
' https://www.ibm.com/us-en/marketplace/personal-communications
    Dim autECLSession, autECLOIA, autECLPS, autECLConnList As Object
    Dim JDE, Enter, Load, F1, F2, F3, F4, F5, ShF4, PageDown, PageUp, Clear As String

    Set autECLSession = CreateObject("Pcomm.autECLSession")
    Set autECLOIA = CreateObject("Pcomm.autECLOIA")
    Set autECLPS = CreateObject("Pcomm.autECLPS")
    Set autECLConnList = CreateObject("PCOMM.autECLConnList")
    autECLSession.SetConnectionByName "A"

    Set JDE = autECLSession.autECLPS
    Set Load = autECLSession.autECLOIA

    Enter = "[enter]"
    F1 = "[pf1]"
    F2 = "[pf2]"
    F3 = "[pf3]"
    F4 = "[pf4]"
    F5 = "[pf5]"
    ShF4 = "[pf15]"
    PageDown = "[Roll up]"
    PageUp = "[Roll down]"
    Clear = "[erase eof]"

    ' Extracting text
    Selection= JDE.GetText (10, 64, 10(spaces required))

    ' Navigating JDE
    Load.waitforappavailable
    Load.WaitForInputReady
    JDE.SendKeys F1
    JDE.SendKeys F2
    JDE.SendKeys F3
    JDE.SendKeys F4
    JDE.SendKeys ShF4
    JDE.SendKeys Clear
    JDE.SendKeys PageDown
    JDE.SendKeys PageUp

End Sub
```

The example above helps me navigate the screens by sending several keystrokes and to extract some text to memory.

Comment: Deleting a question that was almost closed, and reposting the same thing as a new question is almost guaranteed to get a ton of close and down votes. In fact if you aren't careful, you could get locked out. I would edit this into a real question and separate answer quickly. If I were you.

Comment: @jmarkmurphy, you are confused. IBM i Access Client Solutions is not the same as PComm. This is a real task I need to accomplish. The code above worked for and old software we had. I separated both questions as they are for different platforms. Anyways, seeing how much controversy and confusion that question seems to be causing I have now deleted it. In the other comment you asked "
Do you need Set Load = autECLSession.autECLOIA in the code twice? what is the purpose of that? –" Well... no that was a mistake. I just removed that line.

Comment: You are correct, the question says iAccess Solutions, and I read PCOMM.